# MySQL #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax at line 2

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax-error, create-table

What's wrong on this code?  I receive that message when try to import this sql:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''codigo' int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment, 'razao_social' varchar(11) N' at line 2

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `char` (
'codigo' int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
'razao_social' varchar(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
'fantasia' varchar(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
'data_de_cadastro' datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
'cep' varchar(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
'logradouro' varchar(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
'numero' varchar(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
'complemento' varchar(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
'bairro' varchar(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
'cidade' varchar(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
'uf' varchar(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
'cnpj' varchar(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
'insc_estadual' varchar(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
'incs_municipal' varchar(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
'telefone01' varchar(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
'telefone02' varchar(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
'contato' varchar(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
'associados' varchar(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
'funcionários' varchar(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
'data_socio' datatime NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
'data_desligamento' datatime NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
'email' varchar(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
'website' varchar(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
'situacao' int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
PRIMARY KEY  (`codigo`),
UNIQUE KEY `razao_social` (`razao_social`),
KEY `fantasia` (`account_id`),
KEY `cnpj` (`cnpj`),
KEY `insc_estadual` (`insc_estadual`),
KEY `incs_municipal` (`incs_municipal`)
) ENGINE=MySQL;
```

Comment: Don't wrap column names in inverted commas. Use backticks - or nothing.

Comment: Also, while not the cause of your specific error, Aman Aggarwal's point was a good one (pity then that it was deleted). You should not use reserved words as column/table identifiers.

Answer (score 7):

1. you should use backticks `` ` `` in MySQL to escape column name identifiers, not single quotes `'` (*actually, all identifiers, just like you've done with you table name*);
2. you provide datatime as the datatype for `data_socio` and 
   `data_desligamento`, which is invalid (*because it doesn't exist, I think you've meant `datetime`*);
3. MySQL is not a valid `engine` option (*maybe you've meant `MyISAM`?*), [here is a list of storage engines](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/storage-engines.html);
4. `''` is not a valid `default` value for the `datetime` datatype (`data_desligamento`, `data_socio` and `data_de_cadastro`);
5. you are creating an index `fantasia` using a `key` for the column `account_id` that doesn't even exist in your table (*or it is just a typo and either `fantasia` column should be called `account_id` or vice versa? - just guessing here*).

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/27dfa)

Answer (score 0):

Do not use single quotes(') in column names, instead use tild symbol (`).
For example:

```
this column 'razao_social'  should be write as `razao_social`
```

Comment: Is there any technical documentation on what difference it makes?